# Cannot deploy to glassfish 4.1 based cluster?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish, ejb

I had problems configuring GlassFish 4.1 cluster for EJB async timers. Whenever I tried to publish my application I had the following error:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [APP-EAR-1.0] :
Failed to create automatic timers for AsyncTimer -- EJB Timer Service is not available. 
Please see server.log for more details
```

Finally I **somehow** managed to have this working fine some time ago, but it was really try and error. I was sure I knew what I did ... and now when I am trying to document the server installation procedure, after I installed the cluster from scratch on separate set of machines I am hitting the wall again:
When I publish the same app to the new glassfish 4.1 cluster I get the same error:

```
Failed to create automatic timers for AsyncTimer
```

I have no clue what is the reason. I copied step by step all the settings from working glassfish cluster. I have separate connection pool assigned for the timer. I have extra table in the database

```
CREATE TABLE public."EJB__TIMER__TBL" (
  "CREATIONTIMERAW" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "BLOB" BYTEA,
  "TIMERID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  "CONTAINERID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "OWNERID" VARCHAR(255),
  "STATE" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "PKHASHCODE" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "INTERVALDURATION" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "INITIALEXPIRATIONRAW" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "LASTEXPIRATIONRAW" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "SCHEDULE" VARCHAR(255),
  "APPLICATIONID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_EJB__TIMER__TBL" PRIMARY KEY("TIMERID")
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

I am finding the following error in log files:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/nodes/test-1-node/test-instance-1/config/noop=true (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.readScript(Shell.java:218)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:161)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.method(Reflective.java:136)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:469)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:395)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]]
```

Is there a way to start EJB timers without the need to publish the application, so I can easier diagnose the reason of the problem?
Or maybe you can advice what to do to have this cluster start EJB timers as it should.

Hope you can help me, I will appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21194) GlassFish 4.1 bug. You may try the same setup with GlassFish 4.0 or 4.0.1 to see if it works in general.

However, did you make sure that you changed the JDBC resource `jdbc/_TimerPool` on your DAS to reference you cluster database and to be available for the specific cluster? This is required for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I cannot go with older version of glassfish due to some incompatibilities. When it comes to configuration of the version I have: I went into JDBC Connction Pools and created and configured TimerPool, which I can ping. I used this pool in JDBC Resources / __Timer Pool. I did it on the node where DAS is installed, I can't see any specific configuration related to DAS in the console however.

Comment: Are you deploying locally or remotely? There is a similar bug with remote deployments in 4.1. If you're interested, there is a build of GlassFish which is currently looking to fix deployment errors and mentions a patch to Grizzly which is available to try: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/56